# Reload JS function when variable value changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the Instagramfeed by jsanahuja (https://github.com/jsanahuja/jquery.instagramFeed) and everything works fine. Now I want to change the layout of the images when the viewport has a certain width. This works fine by using `($(window).width() < 900)` and changing the `items` and `items-per-row` variables on the end of the function. But by changing the variables, the layout doesn't update, since the function doesn't reload. What's the code to reload a function when a variable gets changed, and is it an effective way of doing it? Or would this slow down the page and would it be a better option to code it that way that I can use CSS for the layout?

Answer (score -1):

you can use [resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) event on window